# jQuery - Looping through elements with specific Attribute

Tags: jquery, custom-attributes, each

I know how to loop through the inputs below, searching for the ones with a specific class of "testers"

And here's how I do that:

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' class="testing" value='John'>
<input type='text' name='lastname' class="testing" value='Smith'>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.each($('.testing'), function() { 
   console.log($(this).val());
 });

});
</script>
```

It outputs the "John", "Smith" as expected.

I want to not use the `class="testing"` and use a custom attribute: `testdata="John"`.

So this is what I'd be doing:

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' testdata='John'>
<input type='text' name='lastname' testdata='Smith'>
```

My goal is to auto-populate the values of each input with whatever is inside `testdata`, but only those detected to have the `testdata` attribute.

This was my failed attempt at using the `$.each` loop:

```
$.each($('input').attr('testdata'), function() {
  var testdata = $(this).attr('testdata');
  $(this).val(testdata);    
});
```

I get this response: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`
Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: side note: use `data-*` attributes, rather than your own made up ones.

Comment: Is that common practice?  If so, that's good to know.  Anywhere you'd recommend I can read up on that?

Comment: It sure is. You can read about it http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/ or http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/

Comment: @ahren thanks!  I definitely prefer to follow standards

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here it is using the HTML5 `data-*` attribute:

HTML:

```
<input type='text' name='firstname' data-test='John'>
<input type='text' name='lastname' data-test='Smith'>
```

JS:

```
$("input[data-test]").each(function(){
    var testdata = $(this).data('test');
    $(this).val(testdata);
});
```

Here it is working: http://jsfiddle.net/SFVYw/

An even shorter way of doing it would be using this JS:

```
$("input[data-test]").val(function(){
    return $(this).data('test');
});
```

Internally it's doing the same as the other JS code but it's just a little more concise.

Comment: A quick addition: this code will only search through inputs with the required data attribute. I needed to target both inputs & selects. Changing the first line to '$("[data-test]").each(function(){' will sort this out...

Answer (score 7):

```
$("input[testdata]").each(function(){
  alert($(this).attr('testdata'));
 // do your stuff
});
```

[**working demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/mohammadAdil/q7jcM/)

Answer (score 3):

if you want to select inputs with specific attribute name and you have these html inputs:

```
<input type='text' name='user1' fieldname="user" class="testing" value='John1'>
<input type='text' name='user2' fieldname="user" class="testing" value='Smith1'>
<input type='text' name='admin1' fieldname="admin" class="testing" value='John2'>
<input type='text' name='admin2' fieldname="admin" class="testing" value='Smith2'>
```

you can loop on admins only like this:

```
$("input[fieldname='admin']").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

by the same way, you can loop for users only:

```
$("input[fieldname='user']").each(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
```

Answer (score 2):

For iterating over all elements with `testdata` attribute and assigning form fields with what their attribute holds try

```
$("[testdata]").each(function(){
    $(this).val($(this).attr('testdata'))
})
```

[works with all elements i guess]